# Armature attaching to mesh on contact

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

Beginner here. I have encountered a weird problem.
Without parenting, as soon as any armature touches a mesh, they somehow connect and move together.
I cant figure out how I caused this and how to turn that off. Can anybody help?
[image: Apart]

I have a newly added bone, entirely unrelated.
Mesh is in a different spot.

[image: Same Spot]

I have only moved the bone towards and into the mesh. This movement is not connected to the mesh, I can move it freely as long as I do not let go while inside a mesh.

[image: Moving Together]

However, if I let go of the button and the armature touches the mesh, from this point on, when I move either the mesh or the armature, they move together.
I do not know how to fix this.
As I said, I did not actively parent the armature, their parent tag is empty, neither did I had the mesh selected while adding the new armature, the mesh does not have any modifier except subdivision surface, and it happens with every armature I might add. What am I missing here?

Comment: Share your file. https://blend-exchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply turn off proportional editing. It's not the armature that is controlling the mesh, but the fact that when you move an object with proportionale editing turned on, every other object nearby will be moved.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That fixed it!